# Performing summation of entities in the Queue [Arena Simulation]

Tags: arena-simulation

In my model in `ARENA`, I have 22 `QUEUE` which I would like to `SUM` their values and display in my animation. The problem is my `expression` length exceeds the 256 character limit and hence I am stuck. Here is what my desired expression looks like:

```
NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N1.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N2.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N3.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N4.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N5.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N6.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N7.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N8.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N9.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N10.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N11.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N12.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N13.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N14.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N15.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N16.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N17.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N18.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N19.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N20.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N21.Queue) + NQ(TRAFFIC LIGHT AT N22.Queue)
```

Any idea how I can perform this summation in my model?

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who comes to this page in future, the workaround I found, was to define `variables` with the value of that long Query mentioned above. Arena doesn't accept long `expression` per se but it does accept long queries as variable values. So I defined the variable and updated that variable in every `ASSIGN` module that I had in the model.